# Is there a way to get Powershell to inherit the cmd prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, cmd.exe

In the cmd shell, it is possible to set (and save) the prompt using the PROMPT command et al. However, when you go into Powershell from cmd, it reverts to the default windows prompt - usually the current directory.

Is there a way to force Powershell to use the current windows prompt?

Comment: No, but you can create your own prompt function and put that into your $profile file

Comment: Well, you ***could*** evaluate `$ENV:Prompt` in the PowerShell `function prompt` and translate the special `$p$g` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working thanks to the very useful comments. Just in case someone else hits the same issue:

```
$profile
```

Yields the location of where the Powershell profile exists (or would exist). If it *doesn't* exist, the following command would create it:

```
new-item -itemtype file -path $profile -force
```

In here, we can just write a prompt function. I generally set mine to the current user so:

```
function prompt {"PS: $(echo 'RobbieDee')>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Prompt` is globally set via `%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`

- **w/o color:**

  ```powershell
  Function set-prompt {
    "$ESC[$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('$' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) $ESC[0m"
  }
  ```
- **w/ color:**

  ```powershell
  switch ($Action) {

      "Default" {
          Function global:prompt {
              if (test-path variable:/PSDebugContext) { '[DBG]: ' }
                  write-host " "
                  write-host ("$ESC[48;2;40;40;40m$ESC[38;2;170;210;0m$(Get-Location) $ESC[0m $ESC[0m")

              if ( $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle -match "Administrator" ) {
                  $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Red'
                  $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) {
                      write-host ('PS $$ ') -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
                  } else {
                      write-host ('PS $ ') -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
                  })
              } else {
                  $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) {
                      write-host ('PS $$ ') -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewLine
                  } else {
                      write-host ('PS $ ') -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewLine
                  })
              }

              return " "
          }
      }
  }

  set-prompt Default
  ```

  - Show a colorized-text prompt for the user and a red-text prompt for an Admin
  - Allows on-the-fly switching of profiles:

    - Copy/paste `Default` section below itself and edit accordingly *(incl. name, i.e. `Default`)*.  Reload session and switch prompt via `set-prompt Default` || `set-prompt <name>`