# How can I set my cmd prompt permanently in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shell, cmd.exe

I know I can set this on the fly with the `PROMPT` command, but how can I set this for every console session?

Comment: Assign `PROMPT` user or system variable to proper value - it will be applied to each CMD session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to the prompt in Powershell since it's the default shell in Windows 10

- Prompt is globally set via `"%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1"`

  - **w/o color:**

    ```powershell
    Function set-prompt {
      "$ESC[$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('$' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) $ESC[0m"
    }
    ```
  - **w/ color:**

    ```powershell
    switch ($Action) {


        "Default" {
            Function global:prompt {
                if (test-path variable:/PSDebugContext) { '[DBG]: ' }
                    write-host " "
                    write-host ("$ESC[48;2;40;40;40m$ESC[38;2;170;210;0m$(Get-Location) $ESC[0m $ESC[0m")

                if ( $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle -match "Administrator" ) {
                    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Red'
                    $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) {
                        write-host ('PS $$ ') -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
                    } else {
                        write-host ('PS $ ') -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
                    })
                } else {
                    $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) {
                        write-host ('PS $$ ') -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewLine
                    } else {
                        write-host ('PS $ ') -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewLine
                    })
                }

                return " "
            }
        }
    }

    set-prompt Default
    ```

    - Show a colorized-text prompt for the user and a red-text prompt for an Admin
    - Allows on-the-fly switching of profiles:

      - Copy/paste `Default` section below itself and edit accordingly *(incl. name, i.e. `Default`)*.  Reload session and switch prompt via `set-prompt Default` || `set-prompt <name>`

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about the console (DOS) shell.

Comment: Although [I did ask](https://superuser.com/questions/1473721/is-there-a-way-to-get-powershell-to-inherit-the-cmd-prompt) about this some time ago... :)

Comment: I'll add my answer to that one =]